# pantheios output to log file with limited size

Tags: c++, pantheios

I'm trying to use the [pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/) in my C++ project. To be specific, I'm using the stock `be.file` back-end to output log into a file. I'm wondering how to limit the size of the log file, so it could be rolled over or overwritten when that limit is exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pantheios 1.0.1 beta 214 (latest AFAIK) does not currently support any limitation on file. Here the snippet from bec.file.h

```
#if 0 /* None of the following are yet supported: */
#define PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_ROLL_ON_SIZE                (0x01000000)
...
#endif /* 0 */
```

Comment: If Pantheios 1.0.1 doesn't support roll-over, what's the constant used for?

Comment: development still in progress. this constants is compiled out with preprocessor #if 0 ... #endif